# Calling the base class's implementation from the derived?

Tags: c++

I want to do what the base does, but then I want to add some derived stuff.

I tried the following but it did not work: (this function is virtual in AguiWidget)

```
void AguiLabel::onSizeChanged( const AguiSize &size )
{
    AguiWidget.onSizeChanged(size);
    updateLabel();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `AguiWidget.onSizeChanged(size);` to `AguiWidget::onSizeChanged(size);`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the scoping operator `::` (i.e. `AguiWidget::onSizeChanged(size)`)

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there, just one small syntax change.

```
AguiWidget::onSizeChanged(size);
```

Answer (score 2):

Close.

```
AguiWidget::onSizeChanged(size);
```