# calling both base and derived methods

Tags: c#, c++

in both C# and C++, is it possible to call both base and derived versions of a method with the same signature instead of overriding the base class version?

Comment: In C# you can simply call `base.Method()` from inside the derived class' `Method`. But I'm guessing that's not what you're trying to do? Theoretically, the outside world should never have to know that your class is derived from anything at all. The abstraction of your derived class should be all it needs to know.

Comment: Probably duplicate of: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262750/calling-the-base-classs-implementation-from-the-derived

Answer (score 5):

In C#, not if the derived method is an override, but yes if it is marked as `new`. You have to be careful when using this construct though, as it isn't really what a consumer of your object would expect to happen in most cases;

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Base baseObject = new Derived();
        Derived derivedObject = new Derived();
        Console.Write(derivedObject.Test());
        Console.Write(baseObject.Test());
        Console.Write(((Base)derivedObject).Test());
    }
}

class Base
{
    public virtual int Test()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public new int Test()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For C++, you can use the scope resolution operator:

```
Derived d;
d.Base::Method();
```