# Access Parent Class virtual method from inheriting Child Class Object

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I would like to know if it is possible to access the base virtual method using a inheriting class (which overrides the method) object.

I know this is not a good practice but the reason I want to know this is if it is technically possible. I don't follow such practice, asking just out of curiosity.

I did see a few similar questions but I did not get the answer I am looking for.

Example:

```
public class Parent
{
    public virtual void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Print in Parent");
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public override void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Print in Child");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         Child c = new Child();
         //or Parent child = new Child(); 
         child.Print();  //Calls Child class method
         ((Parent)c).Print(); //Want Parent class method call
    }
}
```

Comment: I answered virtually the same question yesterday, here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491513/calling-both-base-and-derived-methods/14491581#14491581

Comment: explicitly call the Parent class Print() method. Obviously, as you noted, this architecture is in attempt to reverse polymorphic behaviour -- not wise

Comment: @AdityaSihag; that doesn't work for overridden methods. Only `new`, as per the link above.

Comment: @RJLohan  You are absolutely right.  I don't think I understood what the OP was going for and I've removed my answer.

Comment: So, the consensus is there is not even a workaround to achieve this. I mean technically not possible. It's not that I need this, but was wondering if it could be even distantly possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use reflection to invoke an overridden base method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357729/use-reflection-to-invoke-an-overridden-base-method)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the linked duplicate I commented with, you can do it with some reflection tricks as such:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Child child = new Child();
    Action parentPrint = (Action)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Action), child, typeof(Parent).GetMethod("Print").MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer());

    parentPrint.Invoke();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope - it is not possible to invoke the Virtual method of Base class - The most derived implementation of the method is invoked in such scenarios. In the example given by you, it would print `"Print in Child"` in both the cases.

Comment: Not really! creating a method with same signature in derived class with NEW keyword is shadowing or hiding the method in base class. That means you are invoking the NEW method from the derived class and not the method from base class. Make your print statement to have different literal than in your NEW method of derived class and see it for yourself!

Answer (score 1):

According to me, the best you can do is:

```
public class Parent
{
    public virtual void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Print in Parent");
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public override void Print()
    {
        base.Print();
        Console.WriteLine("Print in Child");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         Child c = new Child();
         //or Parent child = new Child(); 
         child.Print();  //Calls Child class method
         ((Parent)c).Print(); //Want Parent class method call
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't know when this would be helpful. But a decent workaround could be to either overload or write a dummy method that only calls the father class. It would look something like this:

```
public class Child : Parent
{
    public void Print(bool onlyCallFather)
    {
    if(onlyCallFather)
        base.Print();
    else
        Print();
    }
}
```

And then in your main method:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         Child c = new Child();
         child.Print(false);  //Calls Child class method
         child.Print(true);  //Calls only the one at father
    }
}
```

So it would do what you wanted to do. I've actually seen this type of workaround to tell if you want the base method to be called or not.